# Double footer with WKHtmltoPDF

Tags: html, css, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using `WKHTMLToPDF 0.11.0_rc1` with [wkhtmltopdf.tablesplit.js](https://gist.github.com/niflostancu/3683510) to generate some PDF's, the PDF have a static header and footer per page.

The raw html file is just a file with a table, with a some rows in it.

Now this is intended as invoice, and i want on the last page, bottom-aligned, a summary of the products, prices etc. How should I go by aligning it to the bottom?

When I set

```
 body {
    position: relative;
 }

 .summary {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
 }
```

It gets shown at the 1st page, in the middle.

What can I try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create footers with wkhtmltopdf, you need to have them in a separate HTML file from the rest of the content with separate CSS definitions, not in the same file styled with CSS. Output your footer to a HTML file and try a command like this:

```
wkhtmltopdf www.google.com --footer-html myfooter.html output.pdf
```